# Using short circuiting to get first non-null variable

Tags: php, short-circuiting

What's the equivalent of the following (based in JS style) in PHP:

```
echo $post['story'] || $post['message'] || $post['name'];
```

So if story exists then post that; or if message exist post that, etc...

Comment: what's the point in such operator? Don't you know what certain variable you want to output?

Comment: For just 2 arguments you can use: `echo isset($_POST['story']) ? $_POST['story'] : $_POST['message'];`, eventually try to nest it.

Comment: It's based on facebook api stream; only one/two of three will exist per post.

Comment: The page is not full of great advice.  Many of the answers are performing loose comparisons and not strictly checking null-ness.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It would be **(PHP 5.3+)**:

```
echo $post['story'] ?: $post['message'] ?: $post['name'];
```

And for **PHP 7**:

```
echo $post['story'] ?? $post['message'] ?? $post['name'];
```

Comment: This will generate a warning for variables which aren't set

Comment: I am really surprised. I didn't know about this all these years

Comment: The Elvis operator DOES NOT perform the same evaluation as the Null Coalescing operator.  This answer is misleading.

Answer (score 17):

There is a one-liner for that, but it's not exactly shorter:

```
echo current(array_filter(array($post['story'], $post['message'], $post['name'])));
```

[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) would return you all non-null entries from the list of alternatives. And [`current`](http://php.net/current) just gets the first entry from the filtered list.

Comment: Runtimewise, this is going to wind up enumerating all of the values, null or not, right?  The JS example would have stopped at the first non-null value.

Comment: @pinouchon With all due respect, this is not hard to read at all. Although I like the answer from Kluska000 better.

Comment: array_filter returns all the non-null entries from the array, not just the first one.

Comment: @Neets That's why the `current()` wraps it.

Comment: @mario but your answer says "array_filter would return you the first non-null entry". It's wrong. array_filter returns ALL non-null entries, that's why current() is needed.

Comment: LoOks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11159195/2943403

Answer (score 6):

Since both `or` and `||` do not return one of their operands that's not possible.

You could write a simple function for it though:

```
function firstset() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as $arg) {
        if($arg) return $arg;
    }
    return $args[-1];
}
```

Comment: Yea I figured this would be my other way, I was hoping there was an even shorter way of executing.

Comment: The easiest way would be switching e.g. to python :p

Comment: I think passing non-existing var to this function would cause error.

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak -- I thought so too, but I just tested it and it doesn't complain. Though I wouldn't call it "firstset", but maybe "firsttrue".

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 7, you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar
>   for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with
>   isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL;
>   otherwise it returns its second operand.

```
// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
```

Comment: Now we just have to wait for PHP 7 hit production repos, super excited to use this.

Comment: This wouldn't work for the question as asked unless not all the fields even exist because it won't treat null strings (returned if a field is empty) as NULLs.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Adam's answer, you could use the error control operator to help suppress the errors generated when the variables aren't set.

```
echo @$post['story'] ?: @$post['message'] ?: @$post['name'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 1):

That syntax would echo 1 if any of these are set and not false, and 0 if not.

Here's a one line way of doing this which works and which can be extended for any number of options:

```
    echo isset($post['story']) ? $post['story'] : isset($post['message']) ? $post['message'] : $post['name'];
```

... pretty ugly though. Edit: Mario's is better than mine since it respects your chosen arbitrary order like this does, but unlike this, it doesn't keep getting uglier with each new option you add.

Comment: But your option accounts for missing associative key that would generate a php error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
<?php
    echo array_shift(array_values(array_filter($post)));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variety is the spice of life:

```
echo key(array_intersect(array_flip($post), array('story', 'message', 'name')));
```