# Get first non-null value from a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, null

If I have an array:

```
[null, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to get the first non-null value from the array, in this case "a".  How could I go about doing that nice and easily?

Comment: by nice and easy, I meant a short approach.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Not sure about nice and easy. But a short approach might be:

```
 $first = current(array_filter($sparse_array));
```

Where [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) will extract you the "*truthy*" values, thus skipping empty and false entries. While [`current`](http://php.net/current) simply gives you the first of those remaining entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, "truthy" also filters out empty strings, boolean falses and numeric zeroes... otherwise the best solution if the OP wants that logic

Comment: Could even add a custom callback to `array_filter()` to only explicitly filter `null` values. Also just a note, `current()` expects its parameter to be passed by reference, so currently this would issue a "strict standards" notice/warning.

Comment: As alternative for the various interpretations of truthiness, a decision function could be applied: `...(array_filter($arr, "strlen"))`

Comment: Ummm, so `0` will not be returned, if present?

Comment: I see your coding [style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203755/using-short-circuiting-to-get-first-non-null-variable) hasn't changed much... :P

Answer (score 5):

```
function get_first_not_null($array){
  foreach($array as $v){
    if($v !== null){
        return $v;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP asked for a "nice and easy" solution, a simple for-loop is more appropriate than something involving callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getFirstNotNull($array) {
    foreach($array as $val) {
         if(!is_null($val) || !$val) return $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: In second line it shoud be `$array` not `$arrea`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$res = null;
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if ($v !== null) {
        $res = $v;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: More code that mario's solution, but it doubtlessly runs faster -- and it will catch non-null "falsey" values as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could try this:

```
foreach($array as $x) {
    if( $x) break;
}
if( $x) {
    // $x is the first non-null value
}
else {
    // There were no non-null values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `array_reduce`

```
$firstNonNull = array_reduce($array, function($v, $w) {
  return $v ? $v : (isset($w) ? $w : FALSE);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an academic challenge, here is a short-circuiting recursive approach that doesn't rely on a loop and explicitly checks for null-ness (versus falsey-ness). This won't be outperforming other scripts which use `foreach()` and no iterated function calls.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UR3pP)) ([IIFE One-liner Demo](https://3v4l.org/5Z1vN))

```
$array = [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    1,
    null
];

$fn = function($array) use (&$fn) {
    return array_shift($array) ?? ($array ? $fn($array) : null);
};
var_export($fn($array));
```

Or with a more traditional style: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W511X))

```
function getFirstNull($array) {
    return array_shift($array) ?? ($array ? getFirstNull($array) : null);
}
var_export(getFirstNull($array));
```

The body of the function pulls the first element off of the array and return it if it is not null; otherwise, it will make a recursive call upon the remainder of the array (if there are any elements) else return `null` to prevent an infinite loop.