# Pick first non-empty value from a list in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Assuming `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d`, `$e` be some random unknown values. I'd like to pick one value from them which is not empty with priority in that order.

To be brief, I want to achieve the same result as in javascript `return $a || $b || $c || $d || $e || 0;` does.

Currently, in PHP we use (parenthesis are just for readability):

`return $a ? $a : ($b ? $b : ($c ? $c : ($d ? $d : ($e ? $e : 0))));`

Or since PHP 5.3

`return $a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d ?: $e ?: 0;`

I can see the 5.3 syntax is lighter and almost similar to that of JavaScript. But I wonder if there is something more elegant available in PHP.

The other question marked as duplicate to this  asks for a solution to do this. But here I am asking for improvement in case there is something available in PHP natively. This is to ensure we use best possible solution for the said problem.

Comment: What's wrong with `$a ?: $b ?: $c ?: $d ?: $e ?: 0` syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get first non-null value from array php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159062/get-first-non-null-value-from-array-php)

Comment: @Gothdo Nothing wrong with that. I use this often. But I am just curious if there is something better in PHP.

Comment: @Tushar, it sounds different to me "non-empty" and "non-null" in terms of PHP

Comment: The wrong thing is that when the value does not exist it will throw a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function:

```
function firstNonEmpty(array $list) {
  foreach ($list as $value) {
    if ($value) {
      return $value;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then call it like that:

```
$value = firstNonEmpty([0, null, 3, 2]);
```

Comment: Good solution but I would suggest to return null instead of 0 in case of not finding any non-empty item in the last

Answer (score 1):

My original question is about some **native** feature that allows easy pick mechanism for a set of variables. I already indicated that the short ternary operator syntax does it.

However, from the above answers and lot of search around I come to the conclusion that the ternary syntax is the shortest available method in PHP to achieve the said result.

I was expecting something like `pick($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, ....);`, similar to `COALESCE(colname, 0)` of **SQL** but sadly no such function exists yet, AFAIK.

---

Since people are answering with custom functions for this, I tend to put my version of such custom functions.

```
/**
 * Function to pick the first non-empty value from the given arguments
 * If you want a default value in case all of the given variables are empty,  
 * pass an extra parameter as the last value.
 *
 * @return  mixed  The first non-empty value from the arguments passed   
 */
function coalesce()
{
    $args = func_get_args();

    while (count($args) && !($arg = array_shift($args)));

    return isset($arg) ? $arg : null;
}
```

You can call above function with *any number of arguments*, like:

```
$value = coalesce($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, 0);
```

Or, if you have an array instead of independent variables:

```
// Assuming, $array = array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
$value = call_user_func_array('coalesce', $array);
```

Or define another function for array arguments if you like. @gothdo did this pretty well. Just add a default value for fallback and its good to go.

```
/**
 * Function to pick the first non-empty value from the given array
 * If you want a default value in case all of the values in array are empty,  
 * pass the default value as the second parameter.
 *
 * @param   array  $args     The array containing values to lookup
 * @param   mixed  $default  The default value to return
 *
 * @return  mixed  The first non-empty value from the arguments passed   
 */
function coalesce_array(array $args, $default = null)
{
    while (count($args) && !($arg = array_shift($args)));

    return isset($arg) ? $arg : $default;
}
```

---

**I still prefer the ternary syntax, because no other approach will work as good if the variable is not defined at all, and we want to check `isset` instead of `empty` or `truthy` value.**

See the below case. We cannot pass `$a`, `$b` etc... to a function unless we are sure it is defined, otherwise it will raise error.

```
$value = isset($a) ? $a : isset($b) ? $b : isset($c) ? $c : 0;
```

**Looks dirty, but its consistent and straight forward. Plus, native approach is usually better on performance.**

Well, in **PHP 7**, you can use [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) like:

```
 $value = $a ?? $b ?? $c ?? 0;
```

This checks `isset` internally. Pretty clean! Right?