# Coalesce for arrays with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Coalesce isn't really the right word as it returns the first non-NULL value, but hopefully it conveys the intent.

Is there a more-readable and concise way to do get the first defined value of `foo` from `$arr`, `$_GET`, and then `$_POST`?

```
function foo($arr=array())
{
   $arr['bar']=isset($arr['bar'])?$arr['bar']:(isset($_GET['bar'])?$_GET['bar']:(isset($_POST['bar'])?$_POST['bar']:NULL));
   //  ....
}
```

Comment: nesting ternaries is a horrible idea, both from readability and maintainability. And no, there's no shortcut for this. you have to test each var individual with isset().

Comment: Well in the first place I'd use `$_REQUEST` to save yourself the hassle :)

Comment: I'll usually take readability over brevity.  I'd not combine ternaries like that on a single line.

Comment: @Sebas Amen! For some reason devs get so caught up in `$_METHOD` .. `$_REQUEST` gets both get and post.. It's not like you can't as easily fake a $_POST as you can a $_GET

Comment: @ficuscr  Yes, I could use multiple lines but it still isn't very readable and I was trying to make a point.

Comment: @Sebas  Would rather not use `$_REQUEST` and still have to deal with `$arr`.

Comment: @user1032531 How come? I'm curious

Comment: `$arr['bar'] = $arr['bar'] ?? $_GET['bar'] ?? $_POST['bar'] ?? NULL;` - PHP7 only - coming soon on a server near you :-D

Comment: @axiac Would that NULL at the end really be meaningful?

Comment: @Don'tPanic It prevents an `Undefined index: bar` notice. `$a ?? $b` is a shorthand for `isset($a) ? $a : $b` and it doesn't make any test on `$b`. The trailing `?? NULL` makes `$_POST['bar']` being evaluated only if it `isset()` and the notice is avoided. Check it here: http://3v4l.org/hOdZk (PHP 7 only, of course)

Comment: @axiac I see. Thanks for the explanation! I hadn't experimented with `??` yet so I thought a trailing `?? NULL` would be redundant. I had expected `??` to work differently based on its description in the PHP manual "Result: The first operand from left to right that exists and is not NULL. NULL if no values are defined and not NULL."

Comment: @Sebas  Didn't wish to use `$_REQUEST` as it includes cookies.  Guess I could reconfigure PHP to change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is the function you're looking for. Precedence given to the last parametric array.

```
$allData = array_merge($_POST, $_GET, $arr);
return $allData['bar'];
```

Comment: Are you certain that's the solution? What if both POST and GET are filled in? Do we get both the entries? Just asking questions, I'm just wondering

Comment: Like the idea.  One caveat is key type.

Comment: @ficuscr true, but the example use string keys, and $_GET would be expected to have string keys also

Comment: @SamBurns Agreed.  Could you update you answer and show how the arrays should be ordered when passed to `array_merge` as it might be counter intuitive to some without seeing it.  Actually though, this does not account for "first non null".. array flip and hope no values collide?

Comment: Actually `$arr + $_GET + $_POST` would be better than array_merge as it will work also with numeric keys.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues with using `array_merge` or the `+` operator with arrays assuming there is a defined offset but the value happens to be null.

Here are three different approaches and the output from each.

```
<?php

$a = ['foo' => null];
$b = ['foo' => 'bar_b'];
$c = ['foo' => 'bar_c'];

var_dump($a + $b + $c);

var_dump(array_merge($c, $b, $a));  //reverse order here!

function getFirstSetOffsetFromArrays($key, $arr) {
  foreach($arr as $v) {
    if (isset($v[$key]) && !empty($v[$key])) {
      return $v[$key];
    }
  }
}

var_dump(getFirstSetOffsetFromArrays('foo', [$a, $b, $c]));
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) { ["foo"]=> NULL }
array(1) { ["foo"]=> NULL }
string(5) "bar_b"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers here that could work, although none are great to look at: [Using short circuiting to get first non-null variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203755/using-short-circuiting-to-get-first-non-null-variable)

Chosen answer from above modified for your variables:

```
@$arr['bar'] = $arr['bar'] ?: $_GET['bar'] ?: $_POST['bar'] ?: NULL;
```

Comment: What about undefined index notice?

Comment: Probably now we should use the `??` operator, instead of the ternary `? :`, to also avoid "undefined index" error

Answer (score -1):

There are several good examples here already, but I'd prefer to:

```
$arr['bar'] = 
    current(filter_var_array($arr, ['bar' => FILTER_DEFAULT])) ?: 
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'bar', FILTER_DEFAULT) ?: 
    filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bar', FILTER_DEFAULT) ?: 
    null;
```

### Advantages

- Key used only once per array (easier to maintain).
- More readable.
- Selects first valid input (eg first valid number or e-mail).
- Does not trigger undefined index notice.
- No need to use `@`.

### Disadvantages

- Actually longer than original code.
- Makes sense only when `$_GET` and `$_POST` are used, otherwise too complicated.